# Flutter - Convert 24 hour format to 12 hour format

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting time using showTimePicker().

```
  TimeOfDay _selectedTime;

  Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay timePicked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),

      );
    if (timePicked != null)
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = timePicked;
      });
  }
```

But here `_selectedTime` is in 24-hour format. Suppose if I select 3.00 PM then it shows 15.00 i.e. it's in 24-hour format.

How can I convert this time into 12-hour format? i.e It should show me 3.00 PM and not 15.00.

I can write the logic to convert it. But is there anything built in to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `hourOfPeriod` property of `TimeofDay` to return to you the hour in 12-hour format. That, of course, will be without the AM - PM ending :

```
  TimeOfDay _selectedTime;

  Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay timePicked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),

    );
    if (timePicked != null)
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = timePicked.replacing(hour: timePicked.hourOfPeriod);
      });

    print(_selectedTime.toString());
  }
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks :)

Comment: This solution, however, for some reason changes the period parameter to DayPeriod.am even if the time set is a PM time.

Comment: I didn't notice this before @HudsonKim. I will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use `DateFormat` to convert time to 12 hours format with **AM & PM**

```
TimeOfDay? _selectedTime;

Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay? timePicked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
    if (timePicked != null)
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = timePicked;
      });
    // Conversion logic starts here
    DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(
        _selectedTime!.hour.toString() +
            ":" + _selectedTime!.minute.toString());
    var dateFormat = DateFormat("h:mm a"); // you can change the format here
    print(dateFormat.format(tempDate));
  }
```

**Output:**

flutter: 8:00 PM

flutter: 1:00 AM

flutter: 6:00 PM

Comment: use "HH:mm" format in tempDate format to achieve "12:00 PM", otherwise you always get "12:00 AM" even after selecting "12:00 PM" in time picker. @jiesh Mohite

Answer (score 1):

I have created a extension for parsing `TimeOfDay` to 12 hr format

```
extension TimeOfDayExtensions on TimeOfDay {
 String format12Hour(BuildContext context) {
    TimeOfDay time = replacing(hour: this.hourOfPeriod);
    MaterialLocalizations localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);

    final StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();

    buffer
      ..write(time.format(context))
      ..write(' ')
      ..write(period == DayPeriod.am
          ? localizations.anteMeridiemAbbreviation
          : localizations.postMeridiemAbbreviation);

    return '$buffer';
  }
```

You can use like

```
pickedTime?.format12Hour(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

i used [jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) to get 12 hour format and the am/pm

```
_selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay? timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
      hourLabelText: LocalizationKeys.hour.tr,
      minuteLabelText: LocalizationKeys.minute.tr,
    );
    if (timeOfDay != null) {
      DateTime dateTime = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
          DateTime.now().day, timeOfDay.hour, timeOfDay.minute);
      var jiffy = Jiffy(dateTime);
      var format = jiffy.format("hh:mm a");
      _lecturesViewModel.selectedTime.value = format;
    }
```