# How to Convert 24 to 12 hour in date_format package

Tags: flutter, dart

var ToDateTime = formatDate(DateTime.now(), [dd, '/', mm, '/', yyyy, ' ', HH, ':', nn, am]);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Convert 24 hour format to 12 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561585/flutter-convert-24-hour-format-to-12-hour-format)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace HH with hh, which will give you 12 hour format.
For more please visit https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly add the format, here is the solution.

`a` for am/pm

`H` for 24 hours

`h` for 12 hours

```dart
final dateTimeNow = DateTime.now();
final to12hours = DateFormat('d/MMM/yy h:mm a').format(dateTimeNow);
print(to12hours); // flutter: 22/Jul/21 5:14 PM
```

for more info read this doc https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add DateFormat **intl: ^0.17.0** dependency [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)
in your pubspec.yaml file

add below code

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a').format(now);
print(formattedDate);
```

Your output look like this : **22-07-2021 07:30 PM**